# Scale in line drawings

Tags: graphics

I want to draw a line.

```
Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, {10, 0}}]}]
```

Out

[image]

Note that changing the end point  does not affect the displayed line.

```
Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, {20, 0}}]}]
```

Out

[image]

But I want to draw a longer line. How to do it?

Comment: Add `Frame -> True` at the end of `Graphics` to see what happens.  Look up `ImageSize` and `AspectRatio` to control the graphics size and shape.

Comment: `Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, {x, 0}}]},
  ImageSize -> 72*x],
 {{x, 1}, 1, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]`

Answer (score 1):

While the scale answer is technically correct, what you really are trying to do, is to prevent the background from continually resizing to accommodate graphical contents.

The option you want is `PlotRange->{{Xmin,Xmax},{Ymin,Ymax}}` (optionally, Zmin,Zmax for 3D graphics. Another 2 options which affect the output size are `ImageSize` and `AspectRatio`. One scales the whole graphic, another "squishes" the graphic to accommodate a given Y:X ratio. So `AspectRatio->2` would give you a vertical rectangle, and `AspectRatio->1/2` - a horizontal one, while `AspectRatio->1` is a perfect square.

Try this:

```
Graphics[{
          (* your graphics directives here *)
         }, PlotRange->{{0,50},{0,50}}, AspectRatio->1, ImageSize->800]
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

If you have to draw only one line, then it will be automatically scaled as in your example. You can make this line bigger by clicking on the image and make the borders bigger with the mouse...

If you draw two lines then you will see the correct result (ratio)

```
Graphics[{Scale[Line[{{0, 0}, {10, 0}}], 3], Line[{{0, 1}, {10, 1}}]}]
```

in the example above the first line can be scaled